Openssl Assembly file for SHA3 in powerPC
I am new to openssl & working on powerpc architecture device and want to integrate SHA3 from openssl in assembly format. I came across the below link for this:
Source file : https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/sha3.c
Assembly file : https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/sha/asm/keccak1600-ppc64.pl
However, assembly file is encoded as a perl script. how can I get .s file from this ?
& can I integrate this .s + sha3.c + sha3.h in my project for the complete SHA3 implementation ? I am not about complete architecture and want as minimum overhead as possible ?

You need to run the Perl script with some variables set to indicate which flavour of assembly you need to produce an assembly file.  Read the OpenSSL build scripts for how to invoke the Perl script.

thanks. and after the assembly file generation, will the files stated above suffice for integration ?

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Cryptogams_AES

I don't know, but probably?
